# Semantic-ui-react module not found

Tags: semantic-ui-react

I tried to add semantic UI to my react project. I used CDN and included CDN link inside the index file's header.

Then I added a button with semantic UI then it shows an error

> ./src/signupComponent/Signup.js
>   **Module not found: Can't resolve 'semantic-ui-react'** in '/home/kavindu/Documents/react_projects/ocr_web_app/src/signupComponent'

Then I installed semantic UI to the project by this code

```
npm install semantic-ui-css
```

but that problem has not been solved yet, I installed semantic ui several times though.

What is the solution? Error is not solved yet.

Comment: it's something wrong in installing semantic UI react. After successful installing it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can be installed with

```
yarn add semantic-ui-react
```

or

```
npm install semantic-ui-react
```

need to stop the server and install packages.